# How to fail Jenkins build when Mercurial Update fails

Tags: mercurial, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build that checks code out of Mercurial.  There was a situation where the Mercurial repo was corrupted and updates were failing, however Jenkins build would still continue and report Success.  Is it possible to fail the Jenkins build in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue using SVN.

Assuming that Mercurial outputs a warning/error when the update fails, you can use the Text Finder plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin to parse for the warning message and fail if found.

Alternatively, if Mercurial outputs a success message on successful update, you could parse for that and fail if the success message is NOT found.